# Audio captcha implementation using perl

Tags: perl, captcha

I need to implement audio captcha. For this I need a library which can read random string character by character i.e. I need to convert a string to audio file where at a time we are pronouncing single character.

I understand there are many utilities to convert a text to audio. But it pronounce entire word; not read character by character.

```
espeak-gui --stdout 'words to speak' | aplay
```

I don't want to create individual character audio files and then club it. Is there any pre-existing tool for this purpose.

Please note due to limitations i can not use third-party service provider. I just need a library to speedup development.